# Class, located in another Project, is inacessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, class, .net-core, reference

I am getting the error CS0122 class inacessible due to its protection level, this class is located in another project.

Well, I have two projects in the same Net Core solution. For simplicity I am calling project A and Project B, where project B needs to make reference to several classes belonging to project A.

The class TableProcess being referenced has the class and all methods public. The reference between the projects was done via browsing/adding the dll of the project.

This is the TableProcess Class located in the Project A

```
namespace ImageProducer.Repositories
{
    public class TableProcessor
    {

        public TableProcessor(IJobTable jobTable)
        {
            _jobTable = jobTable;
        }


        public IJobTable _jobTable { get; set; }


        public async Task CreateJobTableWithStatus(ILogger log, string jobId, string mode, string imageSource)
        {
            // The initial status "Uploaded"
            EnumJobStatusCode status = EnumJobStatusCode.Queued;

            log.LogInformation($"[+] Creating Job status. Job Id {jobId} - {status} - {JobStatusCode.GetStatus((int)status)}. Mode {mode}. Image Source {imageSource}");
            
            // Initiate the JobTable
            //JobTable jobTable = new JobTable(log, mode.ToString());
            
            // Insert or replace record into the table.
            await _jobTable.InsertOrReplaceJobEntity(jobId, (int)status, imageSource);

            
        }



        public async Task UpdateJobTableWithStatus(ILogger log, string jobId, int mode, int status, string statusDescription, string imageResult)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"[+] Updating Job status. Job Id {jobId} - {status} - {JobStatusCode.GetStatus(status)}");
            
            // Initiate the JobTable
            //JobTable jobTable = new JobTable(log, mode.ToString());

            // Update record into the table.
            await _jobTable.UpdateJobEntityStatus(jobId, (int)status, statusDescription, imageResult);


        }



        public async Task<JobEntity> RetrieveJobEntityByName(ILogger log, int mode, string name)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"[+] Retrieving JobStatus Record By Name, based on filter applied {mode} and Blob Name {name}");

            // Initiate the JobTable
            // JobTable jobTable = new JobTable(log, ConfigSettings.IMAGEJOBS_PARTITIONKEY);

            // Update record into the table.
            return await _jobTable.RetrieveJobEntityByName(mode.ToString(), name);

        }

    }
}
```

These are the lines from Project B where the class Table Process is referenced, and where the error is raised.

```
        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public async Task ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("imagestoprocessqueue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                QueueImageProcessMessage queueMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueueImageProcessMessage>(message);

                // (#) Instatiate TableProcessor but inject JobTable object.
                var tableProcessor = new TableProcessor(new JobTable(_logger, _configuration, queueMessage.imageConversionMode.ToString()));

                // Create record job status with status Queued.
                await tableProcessor.UpdateJobTableWithStatus(_logger, queueMessage.fileName, queueMessage.imageConversionMode, (int)EnumJobStatusCode.Running,null, null);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Log a error here.", ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

If I move the class to Project B, the error doesn't happen. This solution is weird, keep the same class file in both projects in the same solution.

You can se below the both references to classes from Project A.

```
using ImageProducer.Repositories;
using ImageProducer.DataTransferObjects;
```

The classes inside ***DataTransferObejcts*** are all fine, the class ***JobTable*** inside Repositories is fine also, however specifically this ***TableProcessor class*** in Repositories is causing me a headache.

Any help, I am really appreciated, I am a beginner in c# netcore.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot reference the project as a project-reference instead of a dll? As far as I know, it really shouldn't make any difference, but it makes it easier to try things out.

Comment: If you _Go to Definition (F12)_ on `TableProcessor` does it goto your class as expected? you could also try to use the fully qualified class name using the namespace in case there is a duplicate class name in the local namespace.

Comment: Smoknes, When I tried to reference as a project, It didn't work the reference, it was displaying a Yellow triangle in the project name listed in the references, I checked some similar cases, I found a recommendation to reference the dll.

Comment: Chris, I followed your suggestion. F12 takes me to the TableProcessor class as expected, I tried the fully qualified name, the problem persist. As additional information. Project A is a ASP.Net Core Web API project, project B is a Azure WebJob (.Net Framework) project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reference to the project rather than the dll. The reason is that the dll could be out of date compared to the project so maybe the class or methods you're expecting to be able to access are not public, or do not exist, in that version. By referencing the project you ensure that Visual studio will build the project and the resulting dll will be up to date and match your expectations.

If this is giving you issues (as you say a yellow line) it is likely that your target frameworks are different. For example project A is a .Net 4.x project and project b is .Net Standard 2.0, or A is .Net 4.7 and B is .Net 4.0, or something like that.

You cannot reference a dll targeting a newer framework. This would be fine referencing a .Net Standard dll from .Net 4.6 + (or sooner, not sure) as .Net Standard is meant to work that way.

So check the frameworks you're targeting, make them compatible if possible and reference to the project rather than the dll.

Comment: I tried several combinations, so far it didn't work. Azure WebJob project is using .Net Framework 4.7 and ASP.NET Core Web App is using .Net Core 3.1, the target framework are totally different, maybe this is my issue.

Comment: Seems likely. If you can convert the .Net 4.7 project to .Net Standard you can solve the problem. Otherwise you'll need to separate out the functionality you want shared into a new .Net Standard project that each can reference.

Comment: Many Thanks Steve, I will try the second option, so I can learn how a library can be referenced by several projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that you referenced a dll, rather than the project. The referenced version of the dll may not have the class you need.